# C++ Should I destroy old objects in an object when setting new objects?

Tags: c++

Consider the following class declaration:

```
#include "classB.h"
class A {
private:
    B *prop;

public:
    A() { /* does stuff to set up B as a pointer to a new B */
    setB(const B& bar) { /* store a copy of B */
        // how do I manage the old *prop?
        *prop = new B(bar);
    }
};
```

In `setB()` how should manage the memory allocation?  Should I delete the old `*prop`? If so, do I dereference and then `delete`?

Comment: The best answer is to use a unique_ptr<B> instead of trying to do it yourself. But obviously for a homework assignment, where the point may well be to teach you what unique_ptr is taking care of, that could be inappropriate.

Comment: @abarnert Do unique_ptr s automagically clean up after themselves during reassignment? Thanks.

Comment: Well, there's no assignment operator on unique_ptr. You have to explicitly call the reset method instead. But yes, that method will automagically delete the old value, and it also handles all of the other complexities raised in the answers below. See http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr/reset for details. The only problem is that it requires C++11; if you have to use C++03, look at boost::scoped_ptr instead (which is a bit less flexible, but as long as you don't need the extra flexibility it's just as good).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to maintain the state of the object as it was before the operation in the case that the allocation throws, you might be better off implementing it something like this:

```
void setB(const B& bar)
{
    // Do this first, since it could throw.
    B *newProp = new B(bar);

    // Now delete the old one and replace it with the new one.
    delete prop;
    prop = newProp;
}
```

See here (specifically the bit about the strong exception guarantee):

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exception_guarantees

Answer (score 5):

First, you have to set `prop` to `NULL` in the constructor, otherwise you'd get undefined behavior if you attempt to `delete` it.

Second, you don't dereference, you just assign the pointer.

Third, you should delete the memory in the destructor so you don't get a leak.

Last, if you implement the destructor, you should also have a copy constructor and an assignment operator.

```
class A {
private:
    B *prop;

public:
    //set prop to NULL so you don't run into undefined behavior
    //otherwise, it's a dangling pointer
    A() { prop = NULL; }

    //when you set a new B, delete the old one
    setB(const B& bar) { 
        delete prop;
        prop = new B(bar);
    }

    //delete prop in destructor
    ~A() { delete prop; }

    //because you now have a destructor
    //implement the following to obey the rule of three
    A& operator = (const A& other);  //assignment operator
    A(const A& other);               //copy constructor
};
```

Comment: Thanks Luchian!  I have a copy constructor and destructor, I just was too lazy to point them in.  Excellent explanation, thank you!  Much appreciated. :)  I will mark it as a solution after the timer for accepting answers expires.

Comment: It's possibly slightly more idiomatic to write `A() : prop(NULL) {}` rather than assigning to `prop` - not that it matters here though.

Comment: This is neither exception-safe nor self-assignment-safe. (What happens if you call setB(prop)?) Stuart Golodetz' separate answer takes care of those problems. (You also need all of the other changes in this answer, however; that one just covers the setB method.)

Answer (score 0):

If the constructor *always* allocates a new `B`, you can just reuse that space for your copies of other `B` objects.

```
A() { /* does stuff to set up prop as a pointer to a new B */
}

setB(const B& bar) { /* store a copy of B */
    *prop = bar;
}
```

And don't forget to delete `prop` in the destructor.

Comment: In that case (the one where the constructor always allocates a new B), he should probably just have an object instead of a pointer, no?

Comment: That would make it even easier, and solve the potential problems of the missing copy constructor and assignment operator.

Comment: Unless, of course, B can be safely/cheaply/etc. copy-constructed but not copy-assigned, in which case this won't work…